# Can a small creature take the "Bred for War" race trait using the "Adopted" race trait?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The wording of the [Bred for War](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/bred-for-war) trait is as follows:

> **Bred for War**
>
> You tower above most other humans and possess a physique of hard,
>   corded muscle.
>
> Benefit You gain a +1 trait bonus on Intimidate checks and a +1 trait
>   bonus on your CMB because of your great size. **You must be at least 6**
>   **feet tall.** (Emphasis Mine)

Someone on the Pathfinder Society Facebook Group stated they have a Halfling who is 8 feet tall because they used the [Adopted](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/social-traits/adopted) Social Trait to select it. I read the trait as *requiring* you to be six feet or taller to select the trait, not permitting an otherwise Small race to become taller than six feet via its selection.

Comment: Incidentally, being 6 foot tall does not make a halfling a medium creature, so even when "towering above most other humans", you make Intimidate checks against them at -4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the Bred for War racial trait as a member of an adopted species, but that wouldn't give you any sort of benefit if you're less than six feet tall. The Bonus to intimidate is a result of you being unquestionably large.

If you're a halfling adopted by half-orcs you will never be as intimidating as they are because you lack the physical stature the racial trait requires to attain its effect.

By the same token, a Human could use Adopted to get bred for War and be just fine provided they were at least six feet tall. In a way the "six feet tall" requirement is a prerequisite, even if it doesn't seem to be listed as such.

Comment: I think Bred for War is a human trait by default, but thank you. I was pretty sure that you wouldn't be able to automatically be greater than your normal height just for using a trait.

Answer (score 4):

The wording is quite lear there. "You must be at least 6 feet tall." means exactly as it is stated. For this trait to work or have any effect you must be at least this "points finger at the 6 feet line" tall.

I would take it as an oversight that it is not put into a separate required part of the document (there are only very few such oversights for such a large number of traits,...).

So if the halfling is somehow over 6 feet tall  (or just 6 feet) he can use it by all means (and adopted trait). Else no.

Comment: Traits don't have a requirements line, which is probably why it was included in the text instead. Typical requirements are all given by the trait type, including being of a specific race to take a race trait for that race.

Comment: Alternatively, spells often have wording like this, meaning that the _effect_ only occurs if this prerequisite was met, but it is not a prerequisite for the trait itself.

Comment: This would imply that the trait stops working if you're hit with "Shrink Person", though. I wonder if that's intentional, since you still have the same type of build under those circumstances.

Comment: @Erik: I think that is a correct interpretation. If your character is magically shrunk, they keep the trait but lose the benefit for the duration. Likewise a Halfling with the trait, over 3 foot tall naturally,  and under the influence of Enlarge Person could benefit from the the trait bonuses.